# Как использовать Git для контроля версий в Unity3D?

Tags: git, unity3d

Каким образом наиболее просто использовать [Git](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) при работе с Unity, учитывая, в частности, бинарный характер Unity-проектов? Опишите, пожалуйста, рабочий процесс, укажите, что стоит включить в *.gitignore*, какие настройки выбирать в Unity и/или проекте и что ещё нужно при этом учесть?

*Примечание*: я понимаю, что разработчики Unity рекомендуют пользоваться *Asset Server*, но, по ряду причин, я бы хотел использовать Git, то есть использовать Asset Server – для меня не вариант.

<sub>Перевод вопроса [How to use Git for Unity source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225126/) [@PressingOnAlways](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1769276/).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225126/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Рекомендации ниже являются выдержкой из [личного блога](http://www.strichnet.com/using-git-with-3d-games/).*

### Использование Git для 3D-игр

*Примечание: Не так давно GitHub выпустил плагин для Git под названием [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/), позволяющий решить описанную проблему. Теперь вы можете легко и эффективно осуществлять контроль версий для объемных бинарных файлов!*

Git прекрасно работает с 3D-играми, за исключением одного: сохранение версий больших (>5 MB) медиафайлов на протяжении длительного времени (при обновлении архивов версий) может быть проблематичным. Эту проблему мы решили в наших проектах фиксацией только тех бинарных файлов, которые *считаются окончательными*. Наши 3D-художники используют [Dropbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_%28service%29) для работы с [WIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_in_process) — и по вышеуказанной причине, и потому, что это **намного** быстрее и проще (не многие художники горят желанием работать с Git!).

### Процедура работы с Git

Конкретная процедура работы с Git в большей степени зависит от ваших собственных предпочтений, а также опыта и традиций вашей командной работы. Тем не менее, я бы настоятельно рекомендовал методологию с «говорящим» названием «**Git Flow**» [в оригинальной версии автора](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Я не буду чересчур углубляться в суть методологии, поскольку автор прекрасно её описал – к тому же, без лишней «воды», поэтому в ней нетрудно разобраться. Я уже какое-то время использую этот метод для своей команды и на данный момент это лучшая методология из всех нами испробованных.

### Клиентское приложение Git GUI

Это, на самом деле, из области личных предпочтений, поскольку в том, что касается графического интерфейса для Git, возможность выбора есть, включая выбор того, использовать ли графический интерфейс вообще. Спешу предложить бесплатное [приложение SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), поскольку оно отлично сочетается с расширением Git Flow. В [руководстве по SourceTree](http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/08/01/smart-branching-with-sourcetree-and-git-flow/) вы можете прочесть о реализации методологии Git Flow в рамках этого приложения.

### Что игнорировать в Unity3D при работе с Git

```
# =============== #
# Unity generated #
# =============== #
Temp/
Library/

# ===================================== #
# Visual Studio / MonoDevelop generated #
# ===================================== #
ExportedObj/
obj/
*.svd
*.userprefs
/*.csproj
*.pidb
*.suo
/*.sln
*.user
*.unityproj
*.booproj

# ============ #
# OS generated #
# ============ #
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db
```

### Настройки Unity3D для работы с Git

Для версии Unity3D v4.3 и выше:

1. (Для v4.5 и выше пропустите этот шаг) Выберите параметр `External` в `Unity → Preferences → Packages → Repository`.
2. Используйте `Visible Meta Files` в `Edit → Project Settings → Editor → Version Control Mode`.
3. Используйте `Force Text` в `Edit → Project Settings → Editor → Asset Serialization Mode`.
4. Сохраните сцену и проект из меню `File`.

### Дополнительно

Один из отрицательных аспектов использования Unity3D и Git в том, что Git не заботится о пустых папках (а Unity создает для них мета–файлы). Как результат, могут возникнуть не нужные конфликты.

Для решения, добавьте [специальный обработчик](https://github.com/strich/git-dir-cleaner-for-unity3d) в папку `/.git/hooks/` репозитория проекта. Благодаря обработчику после каждого обновления проекта (pull/merge) Git будет проверять удаленные файлы, а также пустые папки.

<sub>Перевод ответа [How to use Git for Unity source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18225479/564240) [@S.Richmond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420787/).</sub>