# Где лучше всего хранить репозиторий Git?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Мы небольшой распределенной командой беремся за разработку крупного проекта Unity. До сих пор работал с [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/product), но на последнем проекте сайт уже стал нас предупреждать, что у нас слишком большой репозиторий и он не должен превышать 2Gb. Поскольку проект у нас содержит много бинарных данных (модели, текстуры, видео и т.п.) размер его может расти существенно.

Поделитесь опытом кто где хранит свои репозитории? Как решаете вопросы с безопасностью? Буду рад любой полезной информации.

Comment: GitHub за 7$ в месяц ничем вас не ограничивает :)

Comment: GitLab.com storage limit raised to 10GB per repo

Comment: Может не стоило нагружать репу бинарными артифактами?

Comment: @vp_arth у нас можно сказать игровой проект и бинарники неотъемлемая часть проекта, которые меняются достаточно активно.

Comment: Gitlab можно поднять на своём сервере…

Comment: Может быть выделить место в своем серваке, сделать там  чистый репозиторий, дать доступ нужным людям и не париться

Comment: @KingPeas это означает, что у вас ошибочный дизайн хранилища. Например, Fedora Linux хранит тарболы пакетов, которые собираются в дистрибутив, а это на минуточку, около 20000 бинарников разной величины (от кбайт до десятков Мбайт). Вы думаете они в системе контроля их хранят?! Конечно нет! Отдельное хранилище со своими метаданными. В системе контроля собственно данные  о сборке пакетов, разные патчи и другие сопровождающие материалы.

Comment: @0andriy а вам с Unity работать приходилось?) Это общий проект для дизайнеров, прогеров, PM, звука и аниматоров. Поэтому в проекте и код и бинарники все до кучи. В конторе мы сделали локальный репозиторий и работаем с ним не задумываясь. А вот для распределенной команды все несколько сложнее именно из за того что размер проектов может расти со временем, к примеру один из наших проектов 2 года жизни достиг 10 гигов. Проект Unity на 95% состоит из бинарников и они то в основном и меняются.

Comment: И как это отменяет мои слова про организацию хранилища?

Comment: @0andriy это сводит ваши слова к "не пользуйтесь git". А такой совет - неправильный...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, вы невнимательно прочитали мой пассаж. Вот пример одного из пакетов в Fedora: https://src.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpms/renrot.git/ Там нет бинарников внутри. Хранить бинарники в Git в большом количестве -- да, лучше не использовать Git для таких случаев вообще.

Comment: @0andriy там внутри есть исходники, достаточные для получения бинарников.

Comment: Я не понял, что вы этим хотели сказать? Бинарники хранятся в **отдельном** хранилище, система контроля версий также задействована, но в ней нет информации о том, **где** хранилище находится.

Comment: @0andriy На сколько я помню Линус Торвальдс как раз и проектировал Git для того чтобы система контроля версий работала с любыми файлами, а не только с исходниками. Андрей вы предлагаете заморочиться и вынести бинарники в отдельный репозиторий? Это столько лишней мороки чтобы потом при необходимости собрать проект. Гораздо проще мириться с ростом репозитория чем просить дизайнеров разбираться с тем как заливать изменения по хитрому.

Comment: Наткнулся на такое описание как лучше всего работать с Git в связке с Unity. [http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/TimPettersen/20161206/286981/The_complete_guide_to_Unity__Git.php] 
А вот тема где обсуждается вопрос взаимодействия на этом форуме [http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519283/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-git-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-unity3d]

Comment: @KingPeas, понимаете, вы путаете *возможность* с *частой необходимостью*, так вот Торвальдс за первое, когда в вопросе мы обсуждаем второе.

Comment: И да, лишней мороки минимум при явной выгоде (и предлагается не *репозиторий*, а *хранилище*). Вы когда-нибудь ощущали некую "медлительность" клонирования или обновления многогигабайтного репозитория? А тут будет очень быстрый репозиторий плюс, скажем, https:// хранилище, доступ которому за O(1).

Comment: @0andriy Хранилище хорошо когда у нас бинарники неизменны, а в проекте Unity они как раз чаще всего и меняются. И при этом, заметьте, дизайнеры также хотят иметь возможность откатиться к нужной версии модели, если вдруг что-то получилось не так как они ожидали после загрузки модели в Unity.

Comment: Да, и в чём собственно вопрос? Есть для этого все необходимые утилиты: http server, xdelta (xdiff / xpatch), NAS, ... Git, как и почти любая, заточенная на сорцы, система контроля версий для (часто меняющихся) бинарников не предназначена. Ставьте уж ClearCase тогда.

Comment: @0andriy Уважаемый, так вы тему то прочитайте) Вопрос был где хранить, а не как)))

Comment: @andreycha Хотел уточнить, а зачем на вопросе убрали Тэг Unity3D, вопрос то касался именно проектов на Unity 3D в виду их специфики работы с бинарниками? Думаю предложенные здесь решения подходят не для всех случаев жизни.

Comment: @KingPeas на мой взгляд, вопрос касается исключительно систем контроля версий. И хранения в них файлов большого размера. А откуда у вас там бинарники -- неважно.

Comment: @KingPeas, уважаемый, так вы в ответ-то вникните, я вам уже разжевал до такой степени, что мы ушли в пусто-порожнее.

Answer (score 7):

Хм, не забрасывайте камнями но я храню их в cloud.mail.ru

как альтернатива яндекс.диск.

[Инструкция](https://www.borodatiyadmin.ru/udalennyj-repozitorij-git-i-yandex-disk/):

```
#Создаем локальный репозиторий
mkdir /mnt/data/Project/test_repo
cd /mnt/data/Project/test_repo
git init
#Создаем файл hello_world.txt c произвольным содержимым
touch hello_world.txt
nano hello_world.txt
#Помещаем только что созданный файл под контроль Git
git add .
#Фиксируем изменения
git commit -m "First commit"
#Создаем удаленный репозиторий
mkdir /mnt/data/Яндекс.Диск/git_repo/test_repo.git
cd /mnt/data/Яндекс.Диск/git_repo/test_repo.git
#Создаем репозиторий без рабочей копии
git init --bare
#Возвращаемся в локальный репозиторий
cd /mnt/data/Project/test_repo
#В локальном репозитории указываем где искать удаленный
#yandex_disk - псевдоним для полного пути к удаленному репозиторию
git remote add yandex_disk /mnt/data/Яндекс.Диск/git_repo/test_repo.git
#Передаем изменения из локального репозитория в удаленный
#master - текущая ветка разработки
git push yandex_disk master
```

Comment: Что храните, простите? Репозитории?

Comment: исходники проектов (не часто публикую) но в целом супер

Comment: https://www.borodatiyadmin.ru/udalennyj-repozitorij-git-i-yandex-disk/

Comment: Заплюсовали коммент, добавил в ответ, чтоб не потерялся)

Answer (score 1):

В Visual studio team-services
https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/

1. приватный
2. бесплатный
3. не ограниченый
4. интеграция с visualstudio
5. удобная работа для команды. Методологии для планирования работы
6. ... (много чего еще)